# Is it a bad practice to use typedef in interface header file?

Tags: c++

I known that it is a bad practice using "using namespace xxx" in a header file, But what about the typedef in a interface header file?

for example:

```
typedef std::set<unsigned int> rsids_type;    //!< typedef something.
struct IRsids 
{
    virtual const rsids_type& GetRsids() = 0;
}
```

On my option, I think this is also a bad practice for that we import a name "rsids_type" into global namespace? so what about the below action?

```
struct IRsids 
{
    typedef std::set<unsigned int> rsids_type;    //!< typedef something inside the interface class.
    virtual const rsids_type& GetRsids() = 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not declare a new namespace in the header file and put the typedef there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unnecessarily polluting *global* namespace with `typedef` is allowed by the language but obviously discouraged by convention.

Namespaces are here (among other things) to avoid names collisions, so put your typedefs within namespaces and/or within classes (as your second example).

`typedefs` usually go into header files, and are often used as a mean of encapsulation (you hide a complex type behind a simple name), e.g. :

```
typedef std::vector<std::vector<double>> Matrix
```

The standard library implementations do it all over the place.

**Note:**

- `using namespace` [should be avoided in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1) because any include of the header brings the entire namespace with it. This is not the case with a typedef, which is basically a type alias, so there is no problem.
- In C++11, `typedef`s and `using` alias are equivalent:

Example:

```
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;
```